# C++ concat three char* strings togther

Tags: c++, string, c-strings, string-concatenation

I am new to c++ and am looking for a way to concatenate three char* strings together ? Can anyone show me some sample code ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Same way as you concatenate four strings, just make the second one empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ you typically use `std::string` for strings. With that you can concatenate with the `+` operator. For instance:

```
std::string s = s1 + s2 + s3;
```

where `s1`, `s2` and `s3` are your three strings held in `std::string` variables.

If you have `s1`, `s2` and `s3` as `char*` or `const char*` then you write it a little differently.

```
std::string s = s1; // calls const char* constructor
s += s2; // calls operator+=() overload that accepts const char*
s += s3; // and again
```

If you really want to use null-terminated C strings, and C string functions, then you use `strcpy` to copy and `strcat` to concatenate.

```
char[SOME_LARGE_ENOUGH_VALUE] str;
strcpy(str, s1);
strcat(str, s2);
strcat(str, s3);
```

where `s1`, `s2` and `s3` are your three strings as `char*` or `const char*`.

Of course, choosing `SOME_LARGE_ENOUGH_VALUE` is the fun part. If this is a learning exercise, then you might like to learn how to allocate the string dynamically.

```
char *str = new char[strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + strlen(s3) + 1];
```

Then you can use the `strcpy`, `strcat` shuffle above. But now you are responsible for destroying the raw memory that you allocated. So, think about how to do that in a robust way, and then use `std::string`!

---

From the comments, it seems you want to concatenate three strings, and then pass the resulting string to a low-level hash function that accepts a C string. So, I suggest that you do all your work with `std::string`. Only at the last minute, when you call the hash function, use the `c_str()` function to get a `const char*` representation of the concatenated string.

Comment: Use of s1 for std::strings, then for char* risks confusing.

Answer (score 3):

```
const char * foo = "foo";
const char * bar = "bar";
const char * baz = "baz";
```

One option:

```
std::string s = foo;
s += bar;
s += baz;
```

Another option:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << foo << bar << baz;
std::string s = ss.str();
```

Another option of last resort:

```
char* s = new char [strlen (foo) + strlen (bar) + strlen (baz) + 1];
s[0] = 0;
strcat (s, foo);
strcat (s, bar);
strcat (s, baz);
// ...
delete [] s;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string s1( "Hello " );
std::string s2( "C++ " );
std::string s3( "amateur" );

s1 += s2 + s3;

std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
```

Or

```
char s1[18] = "Hello ";
char s2[] =  "C++ ";
char s3[] = "amateur";

std::strcat( std::strcat( s1, s2 ), s3 );

std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
```

Comment: and how do i get a char* string back from a std::string ?

Comment: @BadLuckBrian Why do you want it back? What are you going to do with it next?

Comment: OK. So i am using this in Cocos2dx. I have to take a input + currentTime + salt then take a SHA1 hash of the string. The SHA1 function takes a plain char* string. How do i get the std:string into a char* string ?

Comment: @BadLuckBrian Use `c_str()` to get `const char*`

Comment: You can use member function c_str() or data() of class std:string provided that it will not be changed because return type of these functions is const char *

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to concatenate:

```
 #include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* a = "welcome ";
    const char* b = "to C++ ";
    const char* c = "world";
    std::string d(a);
    std::cout<< d.append(b).append(c);

   return 0;
}
```